# show markers on map with getJSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-maps

I am trying to place markers on google map by first finding the latitude and longitude of the user with geolocation and then sending the same using GET request.

Here is my code:

```
function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {

            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "http://localhost/baazar_search/public/walkalong/" + position.coords.latitude + "/" + position.coords.longitude,
                data: {
                    lat: position.coords.latitude,
                    log: position.coords.longitude
                },
                success: function () {
                    window.location.replace("http://localhost/baazar_search/public/layer0");

                }
            });
        });
    } else {
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
}
```

and the second file is like this-

```
function initialize() {
                var mapOptions = {
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng(17, 78.5463),
                    zoom: 10,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                };
                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapOptions);
                $.getJSON("http://localhost/baazar_search/public/walkalong/" + position.coords.latitude + "/" + position.coords.longitude, function (data) {
                    $.each(data.points, function (i, value) {

                        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(value.latitude, value.longitude);
                        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                            position: myLatlng,
                            map: map,
                        });

                    });
                });
            }
            google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

I want to plot the markers on map according to the response I am getting in $.ajax method. The error which I am getting is position not defined. Can anyone one help? I want to use the response when the page is redirected but I am unable to do that..

Comment: position is undefined because ur trying to use it in initialize function

Comment: The geolocation service is asynchronous, you need to use the data (position) in the callback function when/where it is available.  Call initialize in the geolocation callback function.  Call `getLocation` after the DOM has rendered (in the onload event function).

Comment: Yes that's what the problem is..I want to use position in a different file

Comment: Use cookies: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie